# Why is python playing strange sounds whenever I "play" music?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pygame

So i've been trying to play music on Python, what I've done is define variables inside the function and call that function inside a loop.

I've tried changing the parameters and changing the location of the variables which did not try out too well.
I did try to play the music file from another location and it worked, just don't know what's wrong with my function.

```
def main_menu():
    DS.blit(mainmenu, (0, 0))
    pygame.display.update()
    MenuMusic = pygame.mixer.music.load("MainMenu.mp3")
    MenuMusic = pygame.mixer.music.set_volume(0.45)
    MenuMusic = pygame.mixer.music.play()


while loop:
   main_menu()
```

I expect the output to be the sound playing smoothly and properly in the background, but instead I'm getting these strange clicking sounds in the background kinda like someone's drumming.

Comment: This code snippet looks like you're continually re-starting the playing of the MP3.  Try loading and playing the music outside of the main loop.

Comment: I was planning to have the music play as soon as the function was called, what should I do now?

Answer (score 1):

This code snippet looks like you're continually re-starting the playing of the MP3.

It needs to start the playing of the sound, and when it stops re-start it.  The output status of the mixer can be checked with [pygame.mixer.get_busy()](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/mixer.html#pygame.mixer.get_busy), which returns False when there is no sound output.

So for a looping sound, simply test that it's stopped, and re-start:

```
import pygame
import enum

pygame.mixer.init()
pygame.mixer.music.set_volume(0.45)

class GameState( enum.Enum ):
    PLAYING   = 1
    MENU      = 2
    GAMEOVER  = 3

# Set the game state initially.  Start on the menu screen/music
game_state = GameState.MENU

def main_menu():
    DS.blit(mainmenu, (0, 0))
    pygame.display.update()
    ...


while loop:
    # If the sound has not started (or has finished), play it (again)
    if ( pygame.mixer.get_busy() == False ):
        if ( game_state == GameState.MENU ):
            pygame.mixer.music.load( "elevator_music.mp3" )
        elif ( game_state == GameState.PLAYING ):
            pygame.mixer.music.load( "battle_music.mp3" )
        elif ( game_state == GameState.GAMEOVER ):
            pygame.mixer.music.load( "other_music.mp3" )
        pygame.mixer.music.play()

    main_menu()
```

EDIT: I forgot the `pygame` and `enum` imports.

Comment: So i copied the code and got an error of "NameError: name 'Enum' is not defined"

Comment: But thank you for the help, I learned a lot from this and had to change up my code because of this

Comment: @TheForeigner - Oops, I forgot the imports.  Please see updated answer.